# How do I make sure that word converts the right version of my document to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, version

## Background

When I tried to save my word document to a PDF, it created a PDF version of my document successfully with one caveat:  it reverted to an older version of my word document.  In other words, all the edits I made in a session were not there when I converted to PDF.

## Question

Given the situation above, how do I force the convert to PDF feature to have my new changes?

Comment: Did you save the file before converting?

Comment: I did save the file.

Comment: Are you using tracked changes? If so you might need to accept all the changes first.

Comment: I am not using tracked changes.

Comment: Is this problem recurring or did it just happen once? (i.e. have you tried to save a PDF again and was the result the same?)

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything specific.  All you are doing is using a built-in feature within Word to save the document as a PDF.

Comment: If you saved and closed the document, then opened it again, verified that the changes were there, and then converted to PDF, there would need to be something seriously wrong for it to convert an old version.  You shouldn't need to jump through those hoops, but If that does the job correctly, it means there was some glitch in the process when you did it before, and that would be hard to diagnose now.  First step, try to replicate the problem in a meticulous way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that you believe that resaving your Word document should automatically apply your changes to the PDF. If that's the case, here are 3 ways to convert the Word document to PDF.

Option 1: `File | Print | select Microsoft Print to PDF`

Option 2: `File | Save As | select your Save location. In the "save as type" drop-down, select PDF`

Option 3: `File | Export | select Create a PDF/XPS Document`

If you make changes to your Word document, you'll need to repeat one of the above options again to update the PDF document because the changes aren't transferred to the PDF document automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **File | Save As**, use **File | Export | Create a PDF/XPS Document | Options (set options) | Publish**.